# Any way we can passing a value from one page to another page (from difference window)?

Tags: c#, .net

Just wondering will it be possible to passing a value from one page (window browser 1) to another page (window browser 2) without reloading the page?

Example:
I have a page called `test1.aspx`, and inside this page with a button, when user clicked on this button, this will pop-up a new browser by displaying `test2.aspx`.

Inside test2.aspx will contain some data and when user clicked on the 'close' button there, it will passing the value back to `test1.aspx` without reload the page for `test1.aspx` (by fill in all data from `test2.aspx` into the fields in `test.aspx`).

Does anyone know will it possible? also any way I can find out some example? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this by using AJAX and JQuery.

From the POP-UP window you can store the value in the Session variable, You have to do some code of Jquery when POP-UP Window is closed and then reload the particular portion in your page using AJAX. This is how you can do this.

You need to search the Jquery using which you can get the event of closing the POP-UP Window.